# How to save outputs of for loop into a dataframe in Jupyter

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, output, jupyter

I have a for loop as follow:

```
Region = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
i = 5
for Region in Region:
    rr = q * s.at[i+1, 'Value'] 
    tt = w * s.at[i+1, 'Value']
    yy = e * s.at[i+1, 'Value']
    print(Region, rr, tt, yy)            
    i +=1
```

the output is:

```
A 2 5 3 
B 6 2 117 
C 23 875 42 
D 71 26 125 
E 65 24 11
```

How can I save its outputs in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pandas.DataFrame()` method from pandas library [Ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). If you're new to pandas, check [Getting started guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started). You will need to create a dictionary, such as:

```
{"A": {"rr":2, "tt":5, "yy":3}, 
 "B": {"rr":6, "tt":2, "yy":117}}
```

Constructing dataframe with this dictionary will turn keys `A` and `B` into columns and `rr`, `tt` and `yy` into rows. You can always apply `pandas.Dataframe.transpose()` method to the dataframe object to convert columns into rows and vice-versa [Ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

##### Implementation in your code

```
import pandas as pd

#create empty dictionary
d={} 

Region = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
i = 5
for Region in Region:
        rr = q * s.at[i+1, 'Value'] 
        tt = w * s.at[i+1, 'Value']
        yy = e * s.at[i+1, 'Value']
        print(Region, rr, tt, yy)            
        i +=1
        #store data in dictionary
        d[Region] = {"rr":rr, "tt":tt, "yy":yy}

#convert dictionary to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#transpose, if you want
df.transpose()
```